# Method is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i imported one project from github that had tens of errors, now i managed to correct most of them, but 1 is still remaining that i cant figure out.

```
mMenuDrawer = MenuDrawer.attach(this, MenuDrawer.MENU_DRAG_CONTENT);
```

Give me an error:

> The method attach(Activity, MenuDrawer.Type) in the type MenuDrawer is
>   not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity,
>   int)  MainActivity.java   /IPTV/src/by/makarov/video  line 80 Java Problem

Can anyone please explain this error and point me to right direction how to fix it.

Sorry for noobish question, but i am still getting into android develping.

Comment: What is MainActivity? is it extends Activity ?

Comment: Change `mMenuDrawer = MenuDrawer.attach(YourActivityName.this, MenuDrawer.MENU_DRAG_CONTENT);`

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of `attach` needs to be of the type `MenuDrawer.Type`. The possible values are:

- `MenuDrawer.Type.BEHIND`;
- `MenuDrawer.Type.STATIC`;
- `MenuDrawer.Type.OVERLAY`.

For example, change your line to:

```
mMenuDrawer = MenuDrawer.attach(this, MenuDrawer.Type.BEHIND);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the second argument wrong , the method takes MenuDrawer.Type where MenuDrawer is the class and Type is the ENUM as per the library link on Github

https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer/blob/master/menudrawer/src/net/simonvt/menudrawer/MenuDrawer.java

Plz refer to this for proper understanding , you need to use one of these

```
 public enum Type {
    /**
     * Positions the drawer behind the content.
     */
    BEHIND,

    /**
     * A static drawer that can not be dragged.
     */
    STATIC,

    /**
     * Positions the drawer on top of the content.
     */
    OVERLAY,
}

mMenuDrawer = MenuDrawer.attach(this, MenuDrawer.Type.BEHIND);
```